# How do I know when an ajax request is completed

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to know when all ajax calls are complete?,now I just use a delay timeout to wait the request complete,these is a better way?i want make sure ajax requests are completed...

Comment: Are you using a framework/library to make your Ajax requests? Like jQuery or prototype or anything similair?

Comment: You should have included the code that send the ajax request...

Comment: In your title you ask how to know when *one* Ajax request is completed, in the body you ask about *all* Ajax calls. That's a difference, what do you want to know?

Answer (score 4):

The `XMLHttpRequest` object has `readyState` property and `onreadystatechange` that you can manipulate like that:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else { 
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { // xmlhttp.status==200 == successful request
        // What you want here
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "foo_url.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}​
```

You can do it simpler with **jQuery**, if you're using that library:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo_url.php',
    complete: function() {
        // What you want here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery's AJAX, it has a complete option, see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.php',
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert('AJAX call complete');
    }
});
```

Comment: Usually one wants `success` which only runs the callback in case the request was successful.

Answer (score 0):

```
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    // This is when your Ajax request is complete 
                }
            }
```

Comment: That is for successful request, not completed.

Answer (score 0):

that is depend on your library; ex, if you are using jquery then you can use `success:` parameter and if javascript then you can use `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xmlhttp object for ajax call then when xmlhttp.readyState==4 then it is consider as ajax request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
url: 'abc.php',
data: "&id=" + id ;
complete: function(data) {
    alert(data.responseText);
}
});
```